# How to Unmerge CSS and JS in magento using MySQL Command

Tags: mysql, css, magento

I am facing a serious issue on my [website](http://www.ontheway247.com/).I have enabled merge CSS and JS from system-configuration-developer and after I saved it.My site's alignment went wrong and I can't fix it now.
I have tried restoring all files.NOT FIXED
I have created a new database and imported old databases their and changed it in local.xml.STILL NOT FIXED.
I have cleared cached and session too.STILL NOT FIXED.

Comment: though we comiserate, how is the above info enabling us to help ?

Comment: how can e set mege js and css to "NO" ?? USING MYSQL COMMAND LINE. or what's the main rason behind the problem ?

Comment: can you plop some code in here so we can see the overrides ? This is a site for developers, not group therapy :)

Comment: i have enabled jss and css from admin backend of magento,  but now i now the alignment gone wrong and i can set it back to NO. can you help me set it back to NO using mysql command line ? see this screenshot http://prntscr.com/8c0mpd

Comment: just document the code as text here. Going to other links is a non starter. Do you click on any nonsensical link in your Spam folder. No. You have brains. Us too

Comment: This is a Magento Admin issue and would belong over on magento.stackexchange as programmers here are going to go all "buh? where's the code?"

Comment: i cant find the code, cant fix it anyway. cant fix it in magento. cant find it in ftp too

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80765/how-do-i-disable-merged-css-and-js/80766#80766

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past before but I've found that I've been able to set the merge js and css to NO even with the painful version of the admin backend you have. You have to hunt around for the submit button but although it looks strange, it still works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this go to your 'core_config_data' in database and find dev/js/merge_files and dev/css/merge_css_files in 'path'filed after that set thease values from 1 to 0
Please remember clear cache and index management after that
Hope it will work